# Efficiently export very large attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, export, performance

My attribute table is 481'000'000 lines long over 8 columns resulting in approx 38GB as a CSV File.

During the Export it got, however, insanely slow after reaching 95%. I, therefore, am looking for a way to extract the data more efficiently.

I'm using "Export Table", exclude unnecessary columns, and define the output as .csv. I tried the default as .dbf as well, but that fails instantly.

Changing the attributes' format (eg float to integer, string to integer) is a last resort, which I try to avoid.

Comment: You can't write a 38GiB dBase file, since the driver has a 2GiB limit. I'd breaks that dataset into selection sets and use multiple parallel writers.

Comment: Does the export tool complete if you write to a file geodatabase?

Comment: no it did not unfortunately